# Trouble with Microsoft's Windows 7 DVD/ISO USB Tool

Tags: windows-7, usb, usb-flash-drive, iso-image

I downloaded the Microsoft Windows 7 DVD/ISO USB Tool from the Microsoft site, but whenever I try to run the EXE (with elevated privileges or not), instead of running, the LessMSI file (to inspect MSI installation files) pops up....

Any ideas why?? I can't seem to get the Windows 7 DVD/ISO USB Tool to work on my machine - and I re-downloaded it a couple of times, just to avoid any corrupt download - downloaded with Firefox and with Microsoft Internet Explorer - no luck :-(

Thoughts?? I'm running Windows 7 x64 Pro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you create a new user in the control panel and try to reproduce the error?

I guess there are some registry keys that have been messed up. A new user would create a new profile and therefore replacing (at least some) registry nodes.

If it works, you might think about keeping it.
If not, you might need to start living with the thought that you have to reinstall...

Comment: Trouble is: I only have crippled recovery DVD's with my machine, can't re-install from scratch, can I??

Comment: I can't say for sure but as far as I know: nope...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a manual way to do what you want

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

Comment: Thanks! Sounds interesting - but again, seems to require a full Win7 install DVD, which I don't have :-(

Comment: The Microsoft tool requires that also.